# Properly escape a string variable that contains special characters to be used in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, escape-characters, stat

I feel dumb for asking such a simple question but Im absolutely stuck on this one.  I've search everywhere, tried several methods to escape or properly quote this variable, but no matter what when I run this in a shell script I get the following error: `stat: cannot statx 'This is an odd | filename | (name).m4a' : No such file or directory`
The file exists in the directory this is being run at.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="This is an odd | filename | (name).m4a"
FILESIZE=$(stat "%s" "$FILENAME")

echo "Size of $FILENAME = $FILESIZE bytes."
```

When I run this on the commandline it works just fine:

```
$ stat "%s" 'This is an odd | filename | (name).m4a'
```

Comment: your `stat` is different than my `stat`. Are you not missing a `-c` before the format `"%s"`??

Comment: Also, can't reproduce.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I was confused by that too.  Both work, and while searching I saw examples of both.  Im on Kubuntu 22.04 if it matters.  But the result is the same.  Cannot reproduce with the -c%s?  What is your distro?

Comment: So, either you're neither running a BSD-descendent `stat` (which would need `-f`) nor a GNU `stat` (which would need `-c`), or something  is irreproducibly strange with your machine. It's very likely you should have the GNU `stat`, seeing your script specifies it needs to be run with GNU `bash`. Can you paste the output of `stat --help` somewhere, please?

Comment: Thank you, I will verify when I get back home (office is Win10).  Appreciate it, I will update in a few hours.

Comment: This is working for me in MacOS using Bash and the native (NetBSD) `stat` command, no special escaping, just double-quotes around the filename var: `file_name='This is an odd | filename | (name).m4a' ; stat -f '%z' "${file_name}"`.  Is it possible the `$FILENAME` variable is special to the particular shell?  Or the shell has a built-in `stat`?  My `/usr/bin/stat` uses `%z` for file size rather than `%s`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so this did not work this evening `FILESIZE=$(stat "-c%s" "$NAME")` [here](https://pastes.io/3ohqvurb0v) is the output of `stat --help`

Comment: Meh I think I found it.  One of the pipe characters in the script was not the same as a pipe in the filename.  So it was a typo and not found.

Comment: that command `FILESIZE=$(stat "-c%s" "$NAME")` is also not correct. Right would have been `FILESIZE=$(stat -c "%s" "$NAME")`. If in doubt, such things are documented when you run `stat --help` or `man stat`!